# Desktop Application Framework similar to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a desktop application framework similar to Rails:

- Good ORM
- MVC
- Default directory structure
- View Helpers/DSL
- Elegant
- Open Source
- Fun language
- Decently mature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/), a Grails-like framework for Swing application development that fulfills all your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out [Shoes](http://github.com/whymirror/shoes/tree/master)?

Comment: http://unixmonkey.net/?p=27 shows us how to CRUD with shoes.

Comment: With _why's disappearance; I've found this page (http://wiki.github.com/shoes/shoes) to be helpfull

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Bowline](http://github.com/maccman/bowline). It was mentioned in [ruby inside blog](http://www.rubyinside.com/bowline-rails-for-the-desktop-2183.html) recently. I haven't tried it. Tried Shoes though. It is very simple.

There is another one called [Anvil](http://anvil.rubyforge.org/). Anvil is a MVC framework that wants to be equivalent to rails for GUI development. It is based on wxruby. Which makes me want to try it.

Comment: I've stumbled across these also.  Bowline is currently having Thread issues.  Anvil was very inspirational yet incomplete.  I eventually got frustrated with hacking it because of wxruby.  Along these lines, there is also ruby-reactive.  Thx

Answer (score 2):

try Rebol, it's got the simplest gui that is out there. an example of a window with one text field, one button "click me"  and a label "hello" :-

view layout [ field  label "hello"   button "click me" ]

or if you want it in multi line

view layout [
        field
        label "hello"
        button "click me"
]

Answer (score 1):

I've personally ended up using Swing/SWT + JRuby.  The Java cross-platform GUI libraries are just light-years ahead because they're used for IDEs, which are about the most demanding application you can have for a GUI toolkit.  It's nowhere near as elegant as Rails is for the web (and I'm no fan of Rails), but in the long run, it's a much better choice than anything based on wxWidgets or GTK or QT.  It also gives you the option to drop into Java if you have a particular piece that's running too slow.  I wish there were better options, but that's what we've got.

Comment: I've been going that route also so far. I've been using Cheri for the view code, Sequel for the ORM (ActiveRecord), and my own blend of hacks to MVC them together. Most recently I've trying to replace Cheri with an embedded browser. The first embedded browser I found was QWebView (which was available to Java via Jambi). I got QTJruby working, but overall I felt I was bridging to many new technologies and it crashed too often. The next browser I'm going to try and integrate is "DJ Desktop". I also have been considering IronRuby (a little)

Answer (score 1):

Monkeybars is the main solution I'm aware of, but it's not ideal from the point of view of your bullet list. Its "MVC" isn't really like any other interpretation of MVC that I've come across; it's more a convenience wrapper around Swing. At least, that's the way I use it.